# cant remove cookie , what i did wrong?

Tags: php, cookies

classlogin.php

```
/*set cookies*/
            $cookie_name = 'domain[user]';
            $cookie_value = 'domain[authID]';

            // start set cookie //
            //** cookie need to change right away after user press login**//
            // exp  setcookie($cookie_name,'',time()+(60*60*24),'','','',TRUE);
            setcookie($cookie_name,$value,time()+(60*60*24),'/');
            setcookie($cookie_value,$valueID,time()+(60*60*24),'/');
```

classlogout.php

```
<?php
    class checkLogout{
        public function __construct(){
            echo $this->logout();
        }

        public function logout(){
            $cookie_name = 'domain[user]';
      $cookie_value = 'domain[authID]';

            if (isset($cookie_name)) {

            unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
            unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_value]);

            //expire cookie when user click logout
            setcookie($cookie_name, null, -3600, '/');
            setcookie($cookie_value, null, -3600, '/');

            return json_encode($_COOKIE);
        return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }

        }
    }
$checkLogout = new checkLogout();
?>
```

i cant remove my cookie , they exit inside the same folder , so i dont think is path problem ? i check my cookie using json_encode and it wont remove. why?

Comment: Its work for me! check the value of $value & $cookie_name & $cookie_value have the same values in the two php files.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it will replace (`$cookie_name, $cookie_value`) in `unset` function. It will not unset the cookie which you are looking for

```
unset($_COOKIE['domain[user]']);
unset($_COOKIE['domain[authID]']);
```

Probably it should work with below code

```
unset($_COOKIE['domain']['user']);
unset($_COOKIE['domain']['authID']);
```